# Ant Design range picker - how can i disable arrow of future (next) months?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, daterangepicker, react-datepicker

I need to disable future (next) arrows of second calendar. How can i implement it?

[Calendar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1p50.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import classNames from "classnames";
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";
import styles from "./DatePicker.less";
import { RangePickerValue } from "antd/lib/date-picker/interface";

interface Props {
  onChange: Function;
  className?: string;
  placeholder?: [string, string];
  format?: string;
  disableFutureDate?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const { RangePicker: AntdDateRangePicker } = DatePicker;

@observer    
export class DateRangePicker extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
  };

  handleChange = (dates: RangePickerValue): void => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(dates);
  };

  private disableFutureDate = (current: Moment): boolean =>
    this.props.disableFutureDate && current && current > moment().endOf("day");

  render(): React.ReactChild {
    const { className, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <AntdDateRangePicker
        {...rest}
        disabledDate={this.disableFutureDate}
        className={classNames(className, styles)}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

It is component rendering Range Picker. We have no props to add arrow disable functionality. Can we disable it without including props? For example, using css class? If month bigger than month with current date => disable next arrow of future month...

```
render(): React.ReactChild {
    if (!this.model) {
      return null;
    }

    const {
      className,
      withAutoComplete,
      onSearchSettingsChange,
      selectValue,
      options,
      name,
      withSearchByUser,
      withDateSearch,
      searchBoardByDate
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={styles.searchWrapper}>
        {withSearchByUser ? (
          <div className={styles.leftColumnWrapper}>
            <Icon name={name} className={styles.selectIcon} />
            <Select
              className={styles.searchOptions}
              options={options}
              onChange={onSearchSettingsChange}
              value={selectValue}
              dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
            />
            <div className={classNames(styles.searchBox, className)}>
              {withAutoComplete ? (
                this.renderAutoCompleteSearch()
              ) : (
                <>
                  <TextField
                    noLabel
                    name="value"
                    model={this.model}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    className={styles.searchField}
                  />
                  <span className={styles.iconClear}>
                    {this.model.value ? (
                      <Icon name="times" onClick={this.clearInput} />
                    ) : (
                      <Icon name="search" className={styles.searchIcon} />
                    )}
                  </span>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
            {withDateSearch ? (
              <div className={styles.rightColumnWrapper}>
                <DateRangePicker
                  onChange={searchBoardByDate}
                  disableFutureDate
                />
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={classNames(styles.searchBox, className)}>
            {withAutoComplete ? (
              this.renderAutoCompleteSearch()
            ) : (
              <>
                <TextField
                  noLabel
                  name="value"
                  model={this.model}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  className={styles.searchField}
                />
                <span className={styles.iconClear}>
                  {this.model.value ? (
                    <Icon name="times" onClick={this.clearInput} />
                  ) : (
                    <Icon name="search" className={styles.searchIcon} />
                  )}
                </span>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: please share your code here to show what you have tried already.

Comment: i hope i have way to disable future arrows of month and year, but i can't find this way. I shared component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to choose which arrows to remove with the dropdownClassName property of RangePicker and have 4 different classes for the different arrows.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-johnson-qdwjy

Test.js

```
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import "./Test.css";
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

export default () => {
  const className = ["disable-arrow1", "disable-arrow3", "disable-arrow4"];

  return <RangePicker dropdownClassName={className.join(" ")} />;
};
```

Test.css

```
.disable-arrow1 .ant-picker-header-super-prev-btn,
.disable-arrow2 .ant-picker-header-prev-btn,
.disable-arrow3 .ant-picker-header-next-btn,
.disable-arrow4 .ant-picker-header-super-next-btn {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

In Test.js you would be able to put the logic to decide which arrows should be disabled and let dropdownClassName have those classes.
If you only want to disable the buttons I believe you can use `pointer-events: none;` instead of visibility which will work in chrome but maybe not all browsers.

Hope it helps you get the idea of how it is possible.

Comment: Hm...i added your code, but arrows didn't disappear.

Comment: :/ works in codesandbox. Cant say why it wont for you without the code but make sure css is importing correctly. Try inspecting the elements to make sure that the dropdown has the correct classnames

Comment: @shabspb also make sure in inspect that the button elements you are trying to disable have the above classes

Comment: <div class="ant-calendar-picker-container disable-arrow3 disable-arrow4 ant-calendar-picker-container-placement-bottomRight" style="left: 425px; top: 165px;"><a class="ant-calendar-next-month-btn" title="Next month (PageDown)"></a></div>

Comment: I added necessary classes to elements, but property "pointer-events: none;" not applied

Comment: Also i tried to use .ant-calendar-next-month-btn class instead of  .ant-picker-header-next-btn class. But it still doesn't work (

Comment: If i use classes :global(.disable-arrow3 .ant-calendar-header .ant-calendar-next-month-btn),
:global(.disable-arrow4 .ant-calendar-header .ant-calendar-next-year-btn) {
  display: none;
}  all next arrows disappear (at left and right calendars)

Comment: Ok might have something to do with css modules then. Hmm I would think that importing a normal css file (non module) would work too, they should do the same thing. Great that it worked with global atleast :)

Comment: Thank you very much. And now i need to implement logic of hidden arrows. I can't understand how can i receive value of right calendar. I want to compare current date value and value of right calendar, if value of right calendar more than current date value - i delete next arrow buttons at right calendar. What do you mean about it?